# Enable all textfields in UITableViewCell when in Edit mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have a bunch of custom `UITableViewCells` with a label and textbox. I have the textbox disabled but I want to make it so when the user taps the Edit button it will make the textboxes editable. How can I do this so that ALL the `UITextFields` in the `UITableView` become enabled?

I have

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:editing animated:YES];

    if (editing) {

    }
}
```

but cannot add the textbox enable in there since I don't have access to all the textfields. Would I need to add code to grab all the cells and loop through them and enable the textfields?

Comment: I believe you must iterate over the cells and enable the desired text fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do this by setting a `isEditing` `BOOL` on your `UITableViewDelegate` in the `setEditing:animated:` method and just updating visible cells when the value is changed.

```
NSArray *visibleCells = [myTable visibleCells];
for (MyTableViewCell *cell in visibleCells)
    cell.textField.enabled = isEditing;
```

Then, using your `UITableViewDelegate` again, update new cells as they appear in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.textField.enabled = isEditing;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit your subclass of `UITableViewCell` and register your instances for an editing notification in your subclass's `viewDidLoad` or `init` method:

> > [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(disableTextBox) name:@"EditingIsEnabled" object:nil];

And implement a method called `disableTextBox` that disables the text box for that cell.

Then in your `setEditing:animated` method, post the notification when you want to start editing:

> > [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"EditingIsEnabled" object:self];

Override the method `dealloc` in your `UITableViewCell` and remove yourself as an observer, or you'll crash:

> > [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

If you're not using ARC, make sure to call `[super dealloc]`. If you're using ARC, do not call super.

You can do the same thing when you want to disable all the cells, just post a notification with a different name like `EditingIsDisabled`.

Let me know if you need me to flesh out the code a bit more.

Edit: I like DBD's method better in this situation.